# Shrink image using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, image-processing, pixel

I've been trying to shrink an image just using C++. I am quite new to this language.

This is what I have and it works but there is a problem where it leaves unwanted pixels behind.

```
    Rgb temp;
    float scale = 0.8;
    for(int y = 0; y < h*scale; y++)
    {
        int scaleY = (int)(y/scale);
        for(int x = 0; x < w*scale; x++) {
            int scaleX = (int) (x / scale);
            temp = pixels[x + y * w];
            pixels[x + y * w] = pixels[scaleX + scaleY * w];
            pixels[scaleX + scaleY * w] = temp;
        }
    }
```

I have been looking online and haven't found many examples that just use basic C++. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Given pixels your buffer of size N, you want to shrink it so size M where N<M. Here you aren't modifying at all your buffer size, just changing the pixel values. So you must allocate a new buffer pixels2 where put the new values.. You cannot resize the container because you have to keep the original pixel information.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the extra pixel values?

Comment: @user253751 I would like the extra pixels to not appear visible. So that you only see the resized image.

Comment: @Leanne And where is the part where you make the pixels visible? Go to that part, and change it so it doesn't make the extra pixels visible...

Comment: @user253751 Is there any way to fix the problem just inside the method that I have that code in? without changing anything in other parts of my program?

Comment: @Leanne It is impossible to resize an array. So how will the display part know how many pixels to display?